# Egocentric constraint

Tags: syntax

What does it mean that a sentence is an egocentric constraint? I have this sentence: "They really released the bird from the cage" and I have to argue that this is an egocentric constraint. I would really need to find out what this mean. Thank you!

Comment: I've never heard those terms before. You should ask your teacher/lecturer.

Comment: _[Egocentric constraints](http://mitp-cogdev.mit.edu/sites/default/files/journalpdfs/jocn.1997.9.3.348.pdf)_ contrast with _allocentric constraints_ in the physiology of limb coordination. But I've never heard of a sentence being analyzed using them. Y'know, if you're gonna be asking questions about things you don't understand, nobody else will understand them either unless you provide some context -- sentences mean practically nothing out of context, particularly when they're full of strange terms. Where'd they come from, and why do you think they're important to know about?